# Comparing byte[] in LINQ-to-SQL and in a unit test that uses mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, mocking

I have the following method:

```
User IDataContext.AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
{
   byte[] hash = PasswordHasher.HashPassword(userName, password);

   var query =
       from e in mContext.GetTable<User>()
       where e.Email == userName && e.Password == hash
       select e;

   return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When `mContext` is a `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` everything works great. However, when `mContext` is an in-memory mock during my uniting testing, the comparison between `e.Password` and `hash` always returns `false`.

If I rewrite this comparison as `e.Password.SequenceEqual(hash)`, then my unit tests will pass, but I get an exception when I'm talking to LinqToSql. (System.NotSupportedException: The query operator 'SequenceEqual' is not supported.)

Is there a way that I can write this query that will satisfy my unit tests with an in-memory mock, as well as the production component with LinqToSql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting one. I can't think of a convenient way of intercepting the equals without breaking everything, but: are the user-names unique? You could **just** include the username condition in the LINQ, then check the hash in regular c#. In terms of data transferred there is little difference between passing it in and fetching it out, especially if we optimise for the success case (in which case this *reduces* the IO requirements).

Note: return the same result for "not found" and "not a match" if you do this.

Because the byte[] compare no longer depends on special treatment by LINQ-to-SQL, it should work fine in your mock now.

```
var user = (by name).SingleOrDefault();
if(user==null) #fail
bool hashMatch = /* compare array */
if (!hashMatch) #fail
return user;
```

Comment: +1 - I was doing the same sort of thing initially but then I realized I could reduce the IO to *1* request and just compare the passwords with regular LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good candidate for unit testing.  What value is produced by testing SQL's equality by using .Net's equality?

In psuedocode, I see (in essence) three method calls:

```
HashPassword(); 
ConstructQuery();
FirstOrDefault();
```

Each of these three called methods may be unit tested.  What's the point of unit testing the original method?