# Comparing byte[] in Linq query

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a binary column in my SQL table and I successfully query this table with the following C# code:

```
var hash = "http://www.whatever.com".ToSHA256HashBytes();
var landingPage = context.LandingPages.FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.UrlHash == hash);
```

- Please note: "ToSHA256HashBytes" is an extension method I wrote which return a byte[]

This works great because SQL will compare the content of the byte[] and return the record with matching "UrlHash".

however, this doesn't work in my unit test because the comparison is performed in memory and the rules to compare byte[] are, evidently, different. It seems like C# will deem two byte array to be equal if they are at the same location in memory and not by comparing the content of the arrays.

This means that the following unit test will fail

```
var data = new[]
{
    new LandingPage() { UrlHash = "http://www.whatever.com".ToSHA256HashBytes() },
    new LandingPage() { UrlHash = "http://mycompany.com/another/folder/page.php"".ToSHA256HashBytes() },
    new LandingPage() { UrlHash = "http://someothercompany.com/folder/somepage.html"".ToSHA256HashBytes() }
};
var mockData = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
var queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
mockData.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryableData.Provider);
mockData.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryableData.Expression);
mockData.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryableData.ElementType);
mockData.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryableData.GetEnumerator());

var mockContext = new Mock<MyContext>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.LandingPages).Returns(mockData.Object);

var hash = "http://www.whatever.com".ToSHA256HashBytes();
var landingPage = mockContext.Object.LandingPages.FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.UrlHash == hash);
Assert.IsNotNull(landingPage);
```

Is there a way I can write my Linq query so that it works when unit testing as well as when querying the database?

I found a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744031/comparing-byte-in-linq-to-sql-and-in-a-unit-test-that-uses-mocking) but the OP solved his problem by changing his query (which is unfortunately not an option for me) instead of actually finding a solution to his original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
var landingPage = context.LandingPages
    .FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.UrlHash.SequenceEqual(hash));
```

The return value of `SequenceEqual` is `true` if and only if the two source sequences are of equal length and their corresponding elements are equal according to the default equality comparer for their type.

Comment: unfortunately, no this will not work. This idea was mentioned in the other SO question I referenced and, as noted in that question: If I rewrite this comparison as UrlHash.SequenceEqual(hash), then my unit tests will pass, but I get an exception when I'm talking to SQL. (System.NotSupportedException: The query operator 'SequenceEqual' is not supported.)

Comment: @desautelsj Oh, I missed that. What type is SQL using to store your `byte[]` `UrlHash`?

Comment: The SQL column is BINARY(32)

Comment: @desautelsj I don't think you're going to be able to use LINQ-to-SQL and get the `byte[]` comparison to happen server-side, because there are only certain functions it will recognize within the `Expression<...>` arguments you pass to the LINQ methods. The answer to the question you link to seems to provide a solution for the case when you are only using LINQ-to-SQL. Now I understand your problem better, and I don't think there's going to be a single piece of code you can use for both cases (mocked and LINQ-to-SQL). The only (inelegant) solution I can think of is to store the hash as a string.

Comment: @desautelsj A more elegant solution would involve improving the LINQ-to-SQL translator to support `Expression<...>`s that included calls to `Enumerable.SequenceEqual<byte[]>(a, b)`, since binary comparison is an operation supported by most SQL providers, I believe.

Comment: Would there be a way top define a custom function like:
(the following is pseudo-code)
    [DbFunction("Edm", "CompareHash")]
    public static bool CompareHash(this byte[] array1, byte[] array2)
    {
        if (SQL) return array1 == array2;
        else return array1.SequenceEqual(array2);
        return DbFunctions.AddHours(time, value);
    }

Comment: @desautelsj I'm leaning towards keeping it simple and just changing the database type for the hash to a string (Base64-encoded byte array). It will only be 43 or 44 bytes instead of 32 per hash, and the whole problem goes away. This is of course only an option if you're able to change the database table with a migration at this time.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to detect if we are querying a sql database as opposed to a mocked repository? Something like:
  if (IsSqlQuery()) 
  {
    var landingPage = context.LandingPages.FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.UrlHash == hash);
  } else if (IsMocked()) {
    var landingPage = context.LandingPages.FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.UrlHash.SequenceEqual(hash));
  }

Comment: @desautelsj I think you're missing the point I made. The problem isn't just detecting whether you are querying a SQL database as opposed to a mocked repository. The point is that, even if you know you are querying a SQL database, how do you get LINQ-to-SQL to convert a `byte[]` comparison into SQL code that is sent to the database? It doesn't do that right now, and there's no easy way to add that functionality. It's a feature that would have to be added into the LINQ-to-SQL translator, and one that digs down into the expression tree `Expression<...>` passed to the LINQ methods.

Comment: @desautelsj I really strongly suggest replacing your `BINARY(32)` with a Base64-encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I spent some time and here is what might help you.

First I created custom `IQueryable` implementation (Works like adapter: simply translates calls to `IQueryable`-instance (property 'Origin'), passed as constructor parameter).
The only difference is that calls to `CreateQuery` and `Execute` are transformed before execution. We visit each node of expression tree and replace all nodes that are `Equals(byteArray1, byteArray2)` with `Enumerable.SequenceEquals(byteArray1, byteArray2)`

First, here is usage example:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new LandingPage() { UrlHash = "http://www.whatever.com".ToSHA256HashBytes() },
    new LandingPage() { UrlHash = "http://mycompany.com/another/folder/page.php"".ToSHA256HashBytes() },
    new LandingPage() { UrlHash = "http://someothercompany.com/folder/somepage.html"".ToSHA256HashBytes() }
}

var binaryCompareQuery = data
      .AsQueryable()        // Get simple queryable  
      .WithBinaryCompare(); // Use SequentalEquals for byte arrays
```

### Implementation

Here is `IQueryable` adapter:

```
public class BinaryCompareQuery<T> : IQueryable<T>, IQueryProvider
{
    private EqualsReplacer Replacer { get; }
    private IQueryable<T> Origin { get; }

    public BinaryCompareQuery(IQueryable<T> origin)
    {
        Replacer = new EqualsReplacer();
    }

    #region IQueryable implementation

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        => Origin.GetEnumerator();

    public IQueryProvider Provider
        => this;

    public Expression Expression
        => Origin.Expression;

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => Origin.GetEnumerator();

    public Type ElementType
        => Origin.ElementType;

    #endregion

    #region IQueryProvider implementation

    IQueryable IQueryProvider.CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        => Origin.Provider.CreateQuery(Replacer.Visit(expression));

    IQueryable<TResult> IQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression expression)
        => Origin.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Replacer.Visit(expression));

    object IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
        => Origin.Provider.Execute(Replacer.Visit(expression));

    TResult IQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        => Origin.Provider.Execute<TResult>(Replacer.Visit(expression));

    #endregion
}
```

Expression-tree visitor: replaces `Equals` with `SequenceEquals`:

```
internal class EqualsReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    // public static bool Enumerable.SequenceEqual<byte>(this IEnumerable<byte> first, IEnumerable<byte> second)
    private static readonly MethodInfo SequenceEqualMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(x => x.Name == "SequenceEqual")
        .First(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(byte));

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        // Skip all nodes except 'Equal' nodes
        if (node.NodeType != ExpressionType.Equal)
            return base.VisitBinary(node);

        // Skip all 'Equal' nodes with arguments other than byte[]
        if (node.Left.Type != typeof(byte[]) || node.Right.Type != typeof(byte[]))
            return base.VisitBinary(node);

        // Apply rewrite for all inner nodes
        var left = Visit(node.Left);
        var right = Visit(node.Right);

        // Rewrite expression, changing Equals
        return Expression.Call(SequenceEqualMethod, left, right);
    }
}
```

Bonus: Extension method, that allows to add our behavior to any IQueryable

```
public static class BinaryCompareQueryExtensions
{
    public static BinaryCompareQuery<T> WithBinaryCompare<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        var queryable = (enumerable as IQueryable<T>) ?? enumerable.AsQueryable();

        return new BinaryCompareQuery<T>(queryable);
    }
}
```

That's all ;)

Comment: This sounds not bad... but it is not working :( I've fixed null ref setting origin from ctor, but anyway, nothing enters VisitBinary