# Will == always perform a SequenceEqual() on binary in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to compare binary values in a query done by **Linq2sql**.

```
table1.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID.SequenceEqual(id))//ID and id are binary/byte[].
```

but Linq2sql is throwing an exception because `SequenceEqual` cannot be executed in it because it's not defined for SQL.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42502969/939213) which creates a new `Compare` method to confuse Linq into allowing it.

But then I found that `==` works as well since SQL compares binaries byte-by-byte anyway.

But since I saw that answer which didn't bring this simple solution, I was wondering if it will really work all the time.

So, is there any pitfall I'm missing here?

Comment: == should perform with Sql. Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345381/comparing-byte-in-linq-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sonal said `==` will always work for comparing `byte[]` or any other data type that supports equality comparison, However the question you mention does not check equality, but it asks for greather than and less than operators (`>` and `<`) for a data type that does not support them, so a custom comparison method is needed.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. But I'll wait because the first to answer it was actually the [answerer in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502643/how-to-compare-two-byte-arrays-with-greater-than-or-less-than-operator-value-in/42502969#comment94062884_42502969) so I'll see if they post their answer here.